# For which values of $k$ is there an $X$ with $\Omega^kX \cong X$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Bott periodicity can be formulated as $\Omega^2 U \cong U$ where $\Omega$ denotes the based loop space functor and $U$ is the direct limit of unitary groups. The real version can be formulated as $\Omega^8 O \cong O$ where $O$ is the direct limit of orthogonal groups.

> Are there other spaces which are homotopy equivalent to an iterated loop space of themselves? For which values of $k$ is there an $X$ such that $\Omega^kX \cong X$ (but $\Omega^iX \not\cong X$ for $1 \leq i < k$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is easy to construct such spaces.  For instance, let $G$ be any nontrivial abelian group and let $X=\prod_{n=0}^\infty K(G,nk)$.  More generally, given a spectrum $Y$, you could define $X=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \Omega^{\infty-nk}Y$ (though for general $Y$ that $X$ might by chance have a smaller period).

Comment: What do you mean by $\Omega^{\infty - nk}Y$?

Comment: That refers the $(nk)$th space of the $\Omega$-spectrum.  That is, if a spectrum $Y$ is a sequence of spaces $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ together with equivalences $Y_n\to\Omega Y_{n+1}$, $\Omega^{\infty-nk}Y$ refers to $ Y_{nk}$.

Answer (score 3):

There are always such spaces, for silly reasons: you can take $X$ to be a periodic product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

All of the natural examples I know have even period, though.

Comment: Do you know of any 'natural examples' other than the ones I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Michael: there's a $4$-periodic spectrum called the L-theory spectrum that figures in surgery theory. There are also examples with periods like $2, 12, 24, 576$ coming from elliptic cohomology and related ideas.