# When is $BG$ a topological group?

Tags: homotopy-theory, topological-groups, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group, then it has a classifying space $BG$.

> When is $BG$ a topological group?

My motivation for asking this question is that I was thinking about the $B$-analogue of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1692237/39599) and realised it's not clear whether $B^kG$ is defined for $k > 1$.

One case where I know it is true is when $G$ is an Eilenberg-Maclane space, i.e. $G = K(H, n)$. First of all, they are topological groups ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45556/39599)) and by considering the long exact sequence in homotopy associated to the fibre bundle $G \to EG \to BG$, we see that $BG \cong K(H, n+1)$ and is therefore a topological group. It is also true when $G$ is a discrete group for similar reasons.

Comment: $BG$ can never be a topological group when $G$ is nonabelian because the fundamental group of a topological group is abelian.

Comment: @Bruno: but $G$ need not be discrete.

Comment: @Qiaochu Ah. Well then I'm out of my depth. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to homotopy, the answer is if and only if $G$ has the additional structure of an $E_2$ space. (This is exactly the structure that a double loop space has; we need this since a topological group has a classifying space, so if $BG$ has a classifying space then $G$ is a double loop space.)

This is a certain higher categorical version of abelianness. If $G$ is discrete, it must be abelian (by the Eckmann-Hilton argument, which is really about $E_2$ structures), but there are interesting examples beyond abelian or topological abelian groups, such as (again, up to homotopy) the stable unitary group $U$.

The easiest case past the discrete case is the case that $G$ is a groupoid; then $E_2$ means $G$ is a braided monoidal groupoid where every object is invertible. These have a cohomological classification.

Comment: Do you have a reference for what an $E_2$ space is? Also, would I be right in guessing that if $G$ is an $E_k$ space, $B^kG$ is defined?

Comment: @Michael: there are several ways to say what it is on a point-set level, although it is really a homotopical thing; morally it means that $G$ has two monoid structures (up to coherent homotopy) which commute (up to coherent homotopy). For a double loop space the two monoid structures are loop composition in the two loop directions. Traditionally you can use gadgets called $E_2$ operads; May's *Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces* is the canonical reference (May introduced operads in this paper for this purpose). Nowadays other ways of describing this structure are also known. And yes.

Comment: So if $G$ is a topological group satisfying $G \cong B^kG$ for some $k \geq 1$, then $G$ must be an $E_{\infty}$ space? If I'm not mistaken, by using the long exact sequence of homotopy applied to the fibration $G \to EG \to BG$, one can show that any topological group $G$ satisfying $G \cong B^kG$ must be weakly contractible.

Comment: @Michael: yes and yes. The problem is that $G$ cannot have a lowest nonzero homotopy group, since taking $B$ shifts up the homotopy groups by one.

Comment: @Michael: incidentally, another name for $E_{\infty}$ space, at least up to a mild additional condition of being "grouplike," is "infinite loop space." You'll get a lot more search results this way.

Comment: I saw this on nLab, but I didn't understand what it means to be grouplike in this situation.

Comment: @Michael: it just means that $\pi_0$ is a group.

Comment: $\pi_0$ is a group with the multiplication induced by the $E_\infty$ multiplication (which always gives a commutative monoid).