# Eilenberg–MacLane space for explicit group examples

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I am interested in knowing the explicit answers of [Eilenberg–MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) $K(G,n)$ for explicit group examples ($G=$ the entries given at the top row) given below. Can someone fill in the Table?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
G & \mathbb{Z}^n &  \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{R} &\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=U(1) & \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_n \\ \hline
K(G,1) & T^n  & S^1 &  & CP^{\infty} & RP^{\infty} & S^{\infty}/\mathbb{Z}_n \\ \hline
K(G,2)&  & CP^{\infty} & & & &  \\ \hline
K(G,3)&  & & & & &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is not a $K(U(1), 1)$. It is $BU(1)$, but the construction of classifying spaces takes the topology into account while Eilenberg-MacLane spaces are about discrete groups. Anyway, in general these things don't have very explicit descriptions.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan, What is the difference between $BG$ and $K(G,1)$ in general, and in this case?

Comment: They're the same if $G$ is discrete, but $BG$ continues to make sense if $G$ a topological group (and $BU(1) \cong \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$) whereas for $K(G, 1)$ to make sense $G$ must be a discrete group. You can consider $U(1)$ with the discrete topology but then $K(U(1)_d, 1)$ is not $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ anymore.

Comment: $K(\mathbb{Z}^n, 2) = K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)^n = (\mathbb{CP}^{\infty})^n$.

Comment: One model for $K(\mathbb{Z}_2, 3)$ is $TOP/PL$.

Comment: @  Michael Albanese and Qiaochu Yuan, is that true that $K(G,n)=B^nG$ only when $G$ is discrete? This equality does not hold when $G$ is continuous, also for other $n=1,2,3,...$?

Comment: If you put spaces in the after the 'at' symbol, the user doesn't get notified.

Comment: As for your question, if $B^nG$ is defined, then $\pi_{i+n}(B^nG) = \pi_i(G)$ for every $i$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2173890/39599). So if $G$ is a group for which $B^nG$ is defined (that is, it is an $E_n$ space) and $\pi_i(G) = 0$ for $i > 0$, then $B^nG = K(\pi_0(G), 1)$. If $B^nG = K(G, 1)$, then $K(\pi_0(G), 1) = K(G, 1)$ so $\pi_0(G) \cong G$ as topological groups. As $\pi_0(G)$ is discrete, so is $G$. That is, $B^nG = K(G, 1)$ if and only if $G$ is discrete.