# Classifying spaces [related to Eilenberg–MacLane] for explicit group examples

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I am interested in knowing the generalized [classifying spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) (related to [Eilenberg–MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) $K(G,n)$ when $G$ is discrete) for explicit group examples ($G=$ the entries given at the top row) given below. Can someone fill in the Table?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
G & \mathbb{Z}^n &  \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{R} &\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=U(1) & \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_n \\ \hline
BG & T^n  & S^1 &  & CP^{\infty} & RP^{\infty} & S^{\infty}/\mathbb{Z}_n \\ \hline
B^2G &  & CP^{\infty} & & & &  \\ \hline
B^3G &  & & & & &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Here we define $B^nG$ as the $\pi_{n}(B^nG)=G$, while other homotopy groups are zero, $\pi_{i}(B^nG)=0$, for $i \neq n$.

Comment: What's a contractible space on which $\mathbb{R}$ acts freely?

Comment: See also: Which BGs are also K(π,n)s? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348307/79069

Comment: and also a previous trial https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2789563/79069

Comment: I'm saying you should be able to figure out $BG$ for $G= \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @  leibnewtz, it is a point.

Comment: "No" is a pretty good answer to your question.  Most classifying spaces just don't have nice explicit descriptions, though there are a few more cells of your table that can be filled in nicely.

Comment: @ leibnewtz, it is a point with cover R.

Comment: Your definition of $B^n G$ is still not correct if $G$ is not discrete.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan, +1, please feel free to modify my question/ and illuminate. Thanks!